# What is the best way to construct a complex sql query in sqlite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have two tables

**Users**

```
+----+-------+--------------+-------------------------------+
| ID | Login |   Password   |             Guid              |
+----+-------+--------------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | john  | johnpassword | 8f6nf7-r73hd3-43nhd7-df74hd   |
|  2 | mary  | marypassword | 4552mf-234jdf-43njduy-fwujd   |
|  3 | mark  | markpassword | dfh32-fdwe34-3442dr-43wdj45   |
|  4 | tom   | tompassword  | edri84-234jd-234jf-2345jd83   |
+----+-------+--------------+-------------------------------+
```

**Contacts**

```
+----+---------------+------------------+---------+
| ID | RequestSender | RequestRecipient | Status  |
+----+---------------+------------------+---------+
|  1 |             1 |                2 |       3 |
|  2 |             1 |                3 |       3 |
|  3 |             4 |                1 |       3 |
+----+---------------+------------------+---------+
```

RequestSender and RequestRecipient are foreign keys to 'ID' in Users table. Status can be 1 (Requested), 2 (Rejected) and 3 (Accepted)

i would like to write a query to get all john's contacts from Contacts table by providing his **guid** only and get a result like this

**Result**

```
+----+-------+-----------------------------+
| ID | Login |            Guid             |
+----+-------+-----------------------------+
|  2 | mary  | 4552mf-234jdf-43njduy-fwujd |
|  3 | mark  | dfh32-fdwe34-3442dr-43wdj45 |
|  4 | tom   | edri84-234jd-234jf-2345jd83 |
+----+-------+-----------------------------+
```

note that john's ID can be both on RequestSender or RequestRecipient, as long as Status is 3 that is a valid contact relationship

I AM USING SQLITE3 SO I CAN'T DO SOME COMPLICATED STUFF LIKE ON SQL SERVER

Comment: Why do you think "COMPLICATED STUFF" is needed in most cases???

Comment: @LS_dev Lol...i'm not too experienced with SQL syntax, i blame linq2sql for that. That is why i'm thinking it might be a complex query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THAT ISN'T COMPLICATED STUFF AT ALL. THIS IS VERY BASIC SQL:

```
SELECT ID, Login, Guid FROM Users WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT RequestSender FROM Contacts WHERE RequestRecipient=(
        SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Guid=?1
    ) UNION SELECT RequestRecipient FROM Contacts WHERE RequestSender=(
        SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Guid=?1
    )
)
```

Just replace `?1` with desired GUID.

EDIT: Corrected table names.

Comment: There is a small omission in this statement. there is no relationship to the "Users" table which actually holds ID, Guid and Login

Comment: Corrected! One design note: never, but never ever, store passwords!

Comment: Thank you so much...this has saved me from certain embarrassment today :)

Comment: the passwords are encrypted and its a Proof of concept work so we aren't heavy on security atm. thanks for that though